# MD5 está passando verificações

Tags: php

Estou com um problema quando uso MD5 nas minhas senhas, tenho a verificação:

```
if(empty($regPassword)){
    exit('<div class="alert alert-danger margin-top15">&raquo; A <b>senha</b> é necessária e não pode ser vazia.</div>');
}

if(empty($regConfirmpass)){
    exit('<div class="alert alert-danger margin-top15">&raquo; <b>Confirmar a senha</b> é necessário e não pode ser vazio.</div>');        
}
```

Quando uso isso na minha variável:

```
$regPassword        = trim(strip_tags(md5($_POST['regPassword'])));
$regConfirmpass     = trim(strip_tags(md5($_POST['regConfirmpass'])));
```

A verificação não funciona alguém sabe por que?

Código completo em:
[Aqui](http://pastebin.com/DZ2yEb1S)

Comment: Não funciona como? Aqui deu certo colocando a senha igual.

Comment: Não funciona a verificação se o usuário deixar o campo senha vazio cadastra mesmo assim.

Comment: Acontece que a função `md5` vai gerar um *hash* da mesma forma, porém é um *hash* de uma string vazia.

Comment: `trim` e `strip_tags` são desnecessários no teu código pois o `md5` não vai retornar espaços em branco nem tags

Comment: Eu retirei e mesmo assim continua cadastrando mesmo deixando o _input_ senha vazio, retirei o _md5_ e a verificação funcionou, ta estranha quero que funcione com _MD5_

Comment: Você está fazendo a verificação antes ou depois de aplicar o md5?

Comment: Depois de aplicar _md5_ no método **$_POST**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função `md5` gera um *HASH*, isso é feito com cálculos matemáticos em cima da *string* passada. No caso está gerando um *HASH* e verificando se ele está vazio, mais ou menos assim:

```
// md5('') == d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e (string)
if(empty('d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e')){
```

Você precisa checar a variável informada pelo usuário:

```
if(empty($_POST['regPassword'])){
    exit('<div class="alert alert-danger margin-top15">&raquo; A <b>senha</b> é necessária e não pode ser vazia.</div>');
}

if(empty($_POST['regConfirmpass'])){
    exit('<div class="alert alert-danger margin-top15">&raquo; <b>Confirmar a senha</b> é necessário e não pode ser vazio.</div>');        
}
```

Comment: Você resolveu meu problema, mas por que o seu deu certo e o meu não? Eu já tinha feito exatamente igual à você anteriormente.

Comment: Daí eu não sei @GuilhermeAlves, eu teria que ver o código que você fez antes pra saber... Precisando estamos ai... ;)

Comment: Beleza, eu postei no _pastebin_ o código! Valeu muito obrigado.

Comment: @GuilhermeAlves, você precisa fazer a verificação do $_POST **antes** de usar o `md5`.

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida eu já resolvi com a resposta do KaduAmaral. mas Obrigado por tentar me ajudar Rafael Almeida...